# Recommendation letter after 1 month?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, united-states, recommendation-letter

I am applying for a US PhD program. One of my recommendation letters arrived 1 month late.

Should I

1) contact the department

or

2) contact potential supervisors to kindly ask them to consider it, given that the delay was out of my control?

or

3) do nothing?

Answer (score 1):

Contact the department immediately and provide evidence that the letter itself was delayed. Then cc your referee on the correspondence.